# Compress with rar in separates archive on linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, rar

I have a folder full of files, for example:

1. File1.mpg
2. File2.mpg
3. File3.mpg ..

and I would archive them with rar from terminal in separates archives, I would this result:

1. File1.rar
2. File2.rar
3. File3.rar ..

On windows I haven't problem to do it but on linux I don't find how to do it.
I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use for cycle and I reccomend use zip or gzip for compress.

```
for f in /path/to/files; do zip -9r "$f.zip" "$f"; done

for f in /path/to/files; do gzip $f; done
```